# How to send database retrieved values of one jsp page to another jsp page

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

I need to send following values that I retrieved and displayed on the first jsp page to the second jsp page using sessions. One is a string value and the other is a double value. Can someone explain whether it is possible, if so what method to try.

first jsp

```
<form method="get" action="regularMenuCustomer.jsp"> 
    <div class="col-sm-3" data-aos="fade-right">
        <div class="box-part text-center">



        <h3><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${imgBase}" width="200" height="150"/></h3> 



      <h3 style="font-family:Courier New"><%=rs.getString("menu_item_name")%></h3>
      <h4>Rs.<%=rs.getInt("menu_item_price") %></h4>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="CUSTOMIZE NOW" class="btn btn-danger pull-right animated tada delay-2s"/>
    </div>
     <br /><br />
    </div>
 </form>
```

second jsp

```
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-th="Product">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="..." class="img-responsive"/></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <h4 class="nomargin">Product 1</h4>
                                    <p>Item one</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-th="Price">1.99</td>
                        <td data-th="Quantity">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" value="1">
                        </td>
                        <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">1.99</td>
                        <td class="actions" data-th="">
                            <a href="menu.html" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: Create a session object and set attributes to it. Then you can those values in anywhere of your application. Refer https://www.javatpoint.com/session-implicit-object

Comment: I tried it, but it displays "null". I'm retrieving and displaying the values of the first jsp from a database. I need to pass db retrieved information to my second jsp page. One string value and one double value.

Comment: How you redirecting? Is it form submission or from servlet?

Comment: It's a form submission. I redirect using a submit button

Comment: Ok. I can see that you are having `method=get` in the so data can be shared through URl. so create hidden input fields and set data whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="menu_item_name" value="<%=rs.getString("menu_item_name")%>">
<input type="hidden" name="menu_item_price" value="<%=rs.getString("menu_item_price")%>">
```

set these hidden fields inside of your form.
When you submit the form the query strings menu_item_name,menu_item_price are added in the URL so you can easily access these values from the second page.

and from the second-page access, these values using

```
request.getParameter("menu_item_name");
request.getParameter("menu_item_price");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I merged this with my code and edited it according to the way I want to display.